# Forests and farmland are (removed?) because of urbanisation

Tags: word-request

Which word can be used here to express the meaning of "removed"?

> Forests and farmland are --------------- because of urbanization and the growth of population. Some people argue that the only way to curb this trend is for humans to consume less, which is particularly difficult considering that people do not wish to forego the standard of living they have achieved.

Comment: Forests and farmlands are being wiped out?

Comment: The first word came to my mind: *decimated*

Comment: You could also say **shrinking**.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers! How about 'declining'?

Comment: @EmmaXL To find the 'perfect' word requires the community to understand the picture in your mind. Is it a *good* or *bad* or *neutral* removal? Is it caused directly by people (e.g. cutting down trees to make space to build houses), or is it dying off because there are too many people trampling it? Is it a removal that can grow back on its own, or one that is gone forever? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the strong idiomatic expression "swept away":

***[Sweep away](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sweep+away)***:

> - eliminate completely and without a trace.

- Forests and farmland are swept away because of urbanization...